# How to import categories in cs cart

Tags: php, cs-cart

I'm new to cs cart . I need to  import categories . How To do. Please help me.

I genereed the import_category.csv

My import_category.csv have following data

```
category_id;parent_id;id_path;level;company_id;usergroup_ids;status;product_count;position;timestamp;is_op;localization;age_verification;age_limit;parent_age_verification;parent_age_limit;selected_layouts;
default_layout;product_details_layout;product_columns
"1";"0";"1";"1";"1";"0";"A";"11";"10";"1310932800";"N";"";"N";"0";"N";"0";"";"";"default";"0"
```

I dont know its correct or not . Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure will depend on the CS-Cart version you run. The import/export process is described in CS-Cart Knowledge base http://kb.cs-cart.com/import-export .

Make sure the fields in your CSV file have the same names as the ones listed under **Administration > Import data > Products** section of your CS-Cart installation there the categories are to be imported. Also check whether the values of the fields have the correct format. For more information about the correct format read the [Imported fields](http://kb.cs-cart.com/imported-fields-format) format article.